# Access Meta Data from UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, meta-tags

How to access Meta Data of a HTML page loaded into a UIWebView in iOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the meta tag's content by,

```
NSString *graphURL = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByName('facebook_share')
[0].getAttribute('content')"];
```

where you can change the attribute name declared in 'content'

Comment: Thanks. This solution does not need any JavaScript written in the page.

Comment: I think you are missing a ')'
NSString *graphURL = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByName('facebook_share')[0].getAttribute('content')"];

Comment: how to use this function in swift?

Answer (score 2):

To extract the author in

```
<html><head>
<meta name="Author" content="Bloody Mary">
</head><body></body></html>
```

wrap the javascript in a function, save it as file `reportMeta.js` and add it to your project.

```
  // file reportMeta.js
  function reportMeta(){
      alert(document.getElementsByName('author')[0].getAttribute('content'));
  }
```

Then load the file from [webViewDidFinishLoad:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad%3a) and execute it:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"reportMeta" ofType:@"js"];
    NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"reportMeta()"];
}
```

Or, if your JS is short you can just inline it inside Objective-C.

Comment: Actually all I need is the value of content attribute. your last suggestion (which has suggested by @Gaz911) works better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By injecting javascript calls -

```
  var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('META');
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < metas.length; i++)
  {
      ...
  }
```

Comment: There are sample which access the DOM using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString and 'document.getElementByName' as parameters. Looking for a similar syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what do you want to achieve. Do you want to read some info from META, change something? what should javascript function return? Do you mean something like: NSString *result = [ yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('META');" ]

Comment: Yes Piotr, I want to access meta data (Content attribute of an element) using the syntax you have mentioned in comment.