# Read metatags in objective c

Tags: html, objective-c, html-parsing

Is there a way to read HTML metatags from a website in objective-C? Like: http://www.seocentro.com/tools/search-engines/metatag-analyzer.html

Tags are:

```
<title> //// </title> 
<meta name="keywords" content="Keyword">
<meta name="description" content="Description" />
```

Metatags:

- Title tag
- Description tag
- Keywords

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about html meta tags? From an html string, a page accessed by NSURLConnection or from a UIWebView?

Comment: Sorry i edited the post.

Comment: I think you mean the metatarsi in the source code. For example the ones used with Doxygen.

Comment: you have you are looking for in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7023229/648990

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to read meta tags in HTML, you could use an HTML parser.

Here is one:
https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser

As an example of how to use it, here is a question whose answer has a code snippet that reads 'span' tags:
[Simple libxml2 HTML parsing example, using Objective-c, Xcode, and HTMLparser.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020849/simple-libxml2-html-parsing-example-using-objective-c-xcode-and-htmlparser-h)

Answer (score -1):

You can use ReadabilityKit for that: https://github.com/exyte/ReadabilityKit

```
let parser = Readability(url: articleUrl)
let title = parser.title()
let description = parser.description()
let keywords = parser.keywords()
let imageUrl = parser.imageUrl()
```

Comment: In the question title, it clearly says "in Objective-C"
You posted a swift lib with a swift example.